# Maximum number of SXA sites

Tags: sxa

What is the maximum number of sites that we can have under Sitecore Content tree in an SXA implementation? Also, does SXA Site Manager have any similar limits? We are using Sitecore 8.2 with SXA 1.6.

Comment: Can you please specify to what number you are aiming around? Just for indication.

Comment: We are looking for around 1200+ sites

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore supports multi sites. I don't think Sitecore limits us on the number of SXA site we can create within Sitecore Content Tree.

The more SXA sites you have within Sitecore, the more compute resources is required.

Answer (score 0):

We did a large multisite implementation with SXA with around 700+ sites. So, theorotically the product supports. We figured out that though the product doesn't have any documented limitations, as we kept adding sites (SXA sites),  the database grew enormously and some OOTB code modules caused obvious slowness, DB queries took longer as all calls try for locks. After doing Profiler, we did find some OOTB code glitches for which we got patches on Sitecore 8.2 with SXA 1.6. Adding 16 vCPUs, around 128 GB RAM didn't help much due to the product issues.
I believe it would be the same for newer versions too unless if the defects were tracked and fixed.